# regex - how to match all select queries in a file in notepad++

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to pull out all select queries in a file. Actually I need to know how many select queries there are in a script. For that I use notepad++.

I look for strings in the following configurations:

- 'SELECT * FROM'
- 'SELECT aWORD FROM'
- 'SELECT FIRSTWORD, SECONDWORD, THIRDWORD FROM'

I have tried with the following regex:

```
select (\w+)(,\s*\w+)* from
```

This one didn't work in notepad++. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advances.
Manel

Comment: Did you make it case insensitive? I could be wrong, because I've never used notepad++ before, but I don't think `select` is the same as `SELECT`

Comment: @Bryce Siedschlaw: I just tried it with case sensitivity off, doesn't work either. Thinking of a solution now...

Comment: @BoltClock. would `SELECT .+? FROM` work?

Comment: I'd wager Notepad++ has trouble with quantifying subpatterns...

Comment: @Bryce: Yup, though that's a pretty forgiving regex.

Comment: Nevermind... I think he wants to pull each column, if I'm reading his query right

Comment: @Bryce: your approach works pretty well. I need to pull out strings delimited with 'select' and 'from'. I haven't checked the results, but with your aproach, I think, the number of selects is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your regex, it should be this:

```
select[\*]*[\w+]*[,\s*\w+]*from
```

Update: Tried this on Notepad++ 5.8.2 and it works.

As the above regex is a greedy expression and 5.8.2 does not support non-greedy regex, you may have to upgrade to [v5.9.3](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.3.html) which does.
Tried using the below regex and it does show you non-greedy results:

```
select.+?from
```

Comment: Every statement has to be in its own line for greedy matching to not skew the results. Just a tip.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this one, but with the blankspaces after 'select' and before 'from'. Your solution works well. 

But I get cases where it matchs many oder sql queries. For instance:

    select AWORD from ... delete from .... select * from

Anyone knows how to delimite the string? Also, the string begins at 'select' and ends at 'from'

Thanks for your help

Comment: You are right.. Notepad++ 5.8 does not support non-greedy regex. I believe v5.9 might have a newer Scintilla engine. Need to check that.

Comment: Tried it in Notepad++ v5.9.3 and it does support non-greedy regex.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
['"]\s*select[*,\s\w]+from\s*['"]
```

it also matches invalid querys (i think that is not a matter) but respects the desired quotes (and double quotes also)
perhaps you want to add `=` inside the search

Comment: if you are sure that your literals querys allways stars as `'select` and terminates as `from'` a more strict regex can be without both \s*

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ was build on top of scintilla and uses POSIX regex, take a look at [Regular Expressions in SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html)

Based on your example, your probably looking for :

```
select[a-z\*, ]+from
```

I've tested this on Notepad++ 5.9 and it matches the examples you've provided.